# How to install package RSQLite.extfuns in R

Tags: r, rsqlite

I have a problem with installing package RSQLite.extfuns. I get error:

```
package ‘RSQLite.extfuns’ is not available (for R version 3.4.2)
```

I tried to do it manually by downloading file from 
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RSQLite.extfuns/
but also with negative effects. Can anyone solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those functions are now in RSQLite itself.  Invoke the `initExtension` command to access them. This example uses the `variance` function from the extfuns:

```
library(RSQLite)

m <-dbDriver("SQLite")
con <- dbConnect(m, dbname = ":memory:")

initExtension(con)  # access extfuns

dbWriteTable(con, 'BOD', BOD, row.names = FALSE)

dbGetQuery(con, 'select variance(demand) from BOD')
##   variance(demand)
## 1         21.44267

dbDisconnect(con)
```

Also note that sqldf loads them automatically so you don't have to do anything special if you are using it:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf('select variance(demand) from BOD')
##   variance(demand)
## 1         21.44267
```

Comment: How can I get function hflights_sqlite? I am trying to imitate authentication system like in link:
https://gist.github.com/trestletech/9793754

Comment: When I try to run app from link I have error: could not find function "hflights_sqlite". How can I help R to find this function?

Answer (score 0):

The packages has been, as of a few seconds ago at least, removed from CRAN. Your best bet right now is to compile the package by hand. To do this in Windows, you will need a few tools, like the Rtools (and LaTeX, I think).

If you're on a mac or linux, you're probably already set.

The downside of this is that you'll may have to satisfy all the dependencies by hand. Up-to-date packages might work, or they might not. In which case you'll have to install older versions. Consider using [packrat](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/).

Comment: I am working on windows. Can you say how to use Rtools to install interesting for me package? I tried to install libraries which are in  RSQLite.extfuns, but after few I get error: 
Error in hflights_sqlite() : could not find function "hflights_sqlite"

Comment: Depending on your mileage, this may not be a trivial process. How to compile a package has been answered over and over again. Please use your favorite search engine first.

Answer (score 0):

How about installing from source using 'devtools' package (though, it may not work for newer versions of R):

```
devtools::install_version("RSQLite.extfuns", version = "0.0.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```